# Retrieving element in an ArrayList Adapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have created a `listview` that has an image and a button - I am using `ArrayAdapter` to view the items in the `listview`.

When I click on the button I would like to get the details of the item clicked.

So I tried the following:

```
pd = productList.get(position);
```

Where `productList` is `ArrayList<ProductDetails> productList;`

`getproductdetailsbutton` is a button in `productListadapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductDetails>`

```
holder.getproductdetailsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

            String productID = pd.getProductID();
            String productName = pd. getProductName();

            Log.d("Value", " Product Details " + productID + " " + productName);
        }
 });
```

When I click the button from the first item, I get details of the last item displayed on the screen in the log.

How do I get the details of clicked item for that position?

Thanks!

**UPDATE: getVIEW Code:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(contextValue.getAssets(), fontPath);
        Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(contextValue.getAssets(), fontPath2);

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.product_details_items, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
            holder.productgetdetails = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productgetdetails);
            holder.productgetdetails.setTag(position);    

            holder.productgetdetails.setTypeface(tf2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            ProductDetails pd = productList.get(position);

            if (pinexist.equalsIgnoreCase(contextValue.getString(R.string.pinexistvalue)))
            {
                Log.d("Value"," - ID " + pd.getProductID());

                if (logdb.checkproductDetailsExists(pd.getProductID()) == 0)
                {
                    holder.productgetdetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Log.e("Value", " = FINAL" + productList.get(position).getProductID());
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.productgetdetails.setText(contextValue.getString(R.string.nodata));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //DO NOTHING
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ProductDetails pd = productList.get(position);

        Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext())
                .load(pd.getProduct_image())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(holder.image);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: show the full code please

Comment: Try adding `pd = productList.get(position);` inside the click listener, by this, you will get correct position.

Comment: try String productID = productList.get(position).getProductID();

Comment: @AseemSharma : can't add productList.get(Position) inside the clicklistener as position is not accessible.

Comment: @Ankit: can't do that inside clicklistener because position is not accessible.

Comment: @RAMKUMAR where are you using this code? in getView method?

Comment: @Ankit: Yes. That is right. I am getting this issue.

Comment: use final before int position, than you are able to access position

Comment: @Ankit: trying that out. give me second...

Comment: @Ankit: I am always getting product_ID as 1 or 2. when I try the following inside click listener: Log.d("Value", " = FINAL" + productList.get(position).getProductID());

Comment: what is your list size?

Comment: @Ankit  I have totally 6 data.

Comment: @Ankit: I have updated the question with full getview code.

Comment: @007: Updated it with getView code.

Comment: remove ProductDetails pd = productList.get(position); and use productList.get(position).getProductID() every where

Comment: @Ankit: Same. Always 1 or 2. - Check the onlick part. I am using only that.

Comment: @Ankit: I am surprised it is this difficult. Listview with a button is usual design right? How come I am not able to get it correctly.  :(

Comment: what is the use of this if (logdb.checkproductDetailsExists(pd.getProductID()) == 0) ? How many product ID are showing in Log.d("Value"," - ID " + pd.getProductID());?

Comment: @Ankit: As of now if particular details exists in local DB then I am planning to disable the button.

Comment: You can hide the button by using holder.productgetdetails.setVisibility(View.GONE) in else condition. And if you are getting 1 and 2 than in your DB all values are exists rather than 1 and 2

Comment: @Ankit: Nope. There is no data in local DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess(actually I'm confident), you must be declaring `pd` as `global` variable, which gets updated by last item displayed, try to move `pd` into `getView()` and mark it as `final` so you can use it inside `onclick` as in

```
public void getView(){
   final ProductDetails pd = productList.get(position);
   // your code for click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When inflating your layout to view in Adapter
you can set the `OnClickListener` on the button

```
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null,true);
        final Product pd = pdList.get(position);
        //....
        Button btn= (Button) = rowView.findViewById(R.id.getproductdetailsbutton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                    String productID = pd.getProductID();
                    String productName = pd.getProductName();

                    Log.d("Value", " Product Details " + productID + " " + productName);
                }
         });
        //..

        return rowView;

    };
```

Or you can handle ListView `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: How does this? I am not able to access position inside click listener. Please help.